# Price of Bond with irregular long first coupon period

Tags: investing, bonds, financing, spreadsheet, bond-coupons

I'm trying to manually calculate the price of a bond with a long first coupon period, found a few candidate formulas on

Microsoft Excel Document: [OddFPrice](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/oddfprice-function-d7d664a8-34df-4233-8d2b-922bcf6a69e1)

mit.edu: [OddFPrice](http://www.mit.edu/%7Embarker/formula1/f1help/05-n-s18.htm#57530)

WestClinTech.com: [Calculating price of bond with OFC on SQLServer](http://westclintech.com/Blog/tabid/132/EntryId/110/Calculating-the-price-of-a-bond-with-an-odd-first-period-in-SQL-Server.aspx)

The presented formulae vary across these sources, also I can't seem to match the results given by the software when using the formula given for it (microsoft excel for instance). I suspect my current problem is an unclear understanding of the variables used in the calculations. The following is a brief description of my current mental model (using notation on excel):

Example Problem Data:

- Bond Issue Date(m/d/y): 10 / 15 / 2008
- Settlement Date: 11 / 11 / 2008
- First Coupon Date: 1 / 1 / 2010
- Maturity Date: 1 / 1 / 2022
- Coupon Rate: 7.85%
- Frequency of coupon payments: semi-annual
- Yield: 6.25
- Redemption Value per $100 face-value: $100
- Day count basis: Actual/actual

Current understanding of the terms (as described in the given equation on excel page)

- Ai: Number of days from bond **issue date** to **settlement date**
- DCi: Number of days from **issue date** to next imaginary coupon after issue date (not first actual coupon)
- DSC: Number of days from **settlement date** to next imaginary coupon after issue date (not first actual coupon)
- E: Length in days of the **first coupon period**
- N: Number of coupons payable between the **first coupon date**(exclusive) and **maturity date**
- NC (becomes hairy here I think): Number of imaginary coupons between the **issue date** and **settlement date**
- NLi: Length in days of the imaginary coupon period which happens to contain the settlement date
- Nq: Number of imaginary coupon periods between **settlement date** and **first coupon date** rounded down

**I strongly suspect my grasp of these terms is the real problem**, so I'd very much appreciate any of the following:

1. Clarification on the terms I described or confirmation if correct
2. The correct/preferred formula of the three sources
3. A detailed explanation of the problem solving process

NB: I used the term 'imaginary coupon' here in place of *quasi* or *pseudo* coupon, I do not clearly understand the meaning of those terms in these context, or whether they mean the same thing, a clarification would also be appreciated greatly.

I'm happy to provide additional details if required, thanks.